# Move a DOM element Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

For a school assignment we were asked to make a code using jQuery, so that when you hover over an element in a table it takes the data and put it into three different span elements. I think I am close but it is not working properly and right now it just creates a mess on the page.

```
<table id="games">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Titel</th><th>Genre</th><th>Årstal</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="games_tbody">
            <tr class="horror"><td>Outlast</td><td>Horror</td><td>2013</td></tr>
            <tr class="rpg"><td>Dragon Age: Inquisition</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="rpg"><td>Skyrim</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2011</td></tr>
            <tr class="horror"><td>Amnesia: The Dark Descent</td><td>Horror</td><td>2010</td></tr>
            <tr class="simulator"><td>Scania Truck Driving Simulator</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2012</td></tr>
            <tr class="horror"><td>Five Nights at Freddy’s</td><td>Horror</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="simulator"><td>Sims 4</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="rts" id="last"><td>Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos</td><td>Real-time Strategy</td><td>2002</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="" id="delete_game" type="button" class="btn">Delete Game</a>

    <div class="game-of-the-moment">
        <h2>Game of the <em>Moment</em></h2>
        <p>
            <span id="moment_title"></span>
            <span id="moment_genre"></span>
            <span id="moment_year"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

The jQuery I have so far

```
$("#games_tbody tr").on("mouseover", function(){
    $ (this).appendTo("#moment_title");
    $ (this).appendTo("#moment_genre");
    $ (this).appendTo("#moment_year");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
$("#games_tbody tr").on("mouseenter", function(){ //mouseenter is a simpler thing to use
    $("#moment_title").text($(this).children().eq(0).text());
    $("#moment_genre").text($(this).children().eq(1).text());
    $("#moment_year").text($(this).children().eq(2).text());
});
```

Here I select the different spans, then use `this` to find the `td`s *within* the `tr` you are hovering over.

using `mouseenter` makes it so the code doesn't fire when you move the mouse whilst its already inside the tr, and only upon entering the tr instead. Use `mouseleave` to handle the mouse leaving the element

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your current code is `appendTo` you are using it wrong way. ie: you are appending the entire `tr` into each `span` But you have to append only the `td` part of it in respective `span`

So here is my idea of doing it.

- On hover add the new data as html.
- Make sure you extract the proper data and add it into respective span's using `eq(0)` to access the `td` based on index

```js
$(function() {
  $("#games_tbody tr").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("#moment_title").html($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    $("#moment_genre").html($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());;
    $("#moment_year").html($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="games">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Titel</th><th>Genre</th><th>Årstal</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="games_tbody">
            <tr class="horror"><td>Outlast</td><td>Horror</td><td>2013</td></tr>
            <tr class="rpg"><td>Dragon Age: Inquisition</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="rpg"><td>Skyrim</td><td>Role-playing Game</td><td>2011</td></tr>
            <tr class="horror"><td>Amnesia: The Dark Descent</td><td>Horror</td><td>2010</td></tr>
            <tr class="simulator"><td>Scania Truck Driving Simulator</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2012</td></tr>
            <tr class="horror"><td>Five Nights at Freddy’s</td><td>Horror</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="simulator"><td>Sims 4</td><td>Simulator</td><td>2014</td></tr>
            <tr class="rts" id="last"><td>Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos</td><td>Real-time Strategy</td><td>2002</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="" id="delete_game" type="button" class="btn">Delete Game</a>

    <div class="game-of-the-moment">
        <h2>Game of the <em>Moment</em></h2>
        <p>
            <b>Title:</b><span id="moment_title"></span> <br/>         
             <b>Genre:</b><span id="moment_genre"></span><br/>
             <b>Arstal:</b><span id="moment_year"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: @JulieBang  Glad I could help..Also if this resolved you issue, you can mark this as answer.